# Can't navigate to page in ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

Every time I try to add an entry in my entry page that directs back to the journal page I can no longer go back to the home page when I press the back button. Sometimes it works but most of the time I get stuck in the journal page

The navigation looks like this to which I get stuck in my journal page when I press the back button so I can't go back to my home page.

```
home page -> journal page -> add entry page -> journal page (gets stuck here)
```

But if I navigate like this I have no problem going back to the home page.

```
home page -> journal page -> home page
```

My code in the home page to navigate to journal page

```
 goToPage(page_name) {
    console.log('Going to page ', page_name);
    //some codes here
    this.nav.navigateForward(page_name);
  }//end of method
```

My code in journal page to navigate to add entry page

```
 <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button href="/journal/add" routerDirection="forward" color='primary'>
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
```

My code in add entry page to navigate back to  journal page

```
  async goBack() {
    console.log("go back to previous page");
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: 'Are you sure you want to exit?',
      subHeader: 'Your progress will be lost.',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Progress lost');
            this.nav.navigateBack('journal');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'No',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Continue');
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();

  }//end of method
```

My code in journal page to navigate to home page

```
  goBack() {
    console.log('going back to home page');//this prints out when I get stuck but doesn't go back to home
    this.nav.navigateBack('home');
  }
```

Comment: In fab button, use routerLink="..." instead of href, and for Routing, set this.router.navigate(['...']); and to go back to home use nav but for setRoot('home');

Answer (score 0):

Instead of navigateBack method, import Location and use back method provided by it.

```
import { Location } from "@angular/common";
constructor(private location: Location) { }

myBackButton(){
 this.location.back();
}
```

Hope it will be helpful :)